# Avoiding type casting in pattern matching

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-erasure

Given a hypothetical mutable linked list (let's assume this is a given structure -- so no suggestions about changing it, please):

```
trait CList[T]
trait CNil [T] extends CList[T]
trait CCons[T] extends CList[T] {
  def head: T
  def tail: CList[T]
}
```

And given Scala's type erasure, how can I iterate through it without casting:

```
@annotation.tailrec def lastValue[T](l: CList[T]): Option[T] = l match {
  case _: CNil [_] => None
  case c: CCons[_] => lastValue(c.asInstanceOf[CCons[T]]) // ouch!
}
```

`CList` is invariant in `T` so there should be way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try defining extractors:

```
object CNil {
  def unapply[T](clist: CList[T]): Boolean = clist.isInstanceOf[CNil[_]]
}

object CCons {
  def unapply[T](clist: CList[T]): Option[(T, CList[T])] = clist match {
    case _: CNil[_] => None
    case c: CCons[_] => Some(c.head, c.tail)
  }

}

@annotation.tailrec def lastValue[T](l: CList[T]): Option[T] = l match {
  case CNil() => None
  case CCons(head, tail) => lastValue(tail)
}
```

You may have to give them another name if you can't put them in the same files as where the original traits are defined.

On another point, the implementation of your `lastValue` function probably doesn't do what you expect… How about this one instead?

```
def lastValue[T](clist: CList[T]): Option[T] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def lastValue0(prevValue: Option[T], clist: CList[T]): Option[T] =
    clist match {
      case CNil() => prevValue
      case CCons(head, tail) => lastValue0(Some(head), tail)
    }

  lastValue0(None, clist)
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, not bad. Yes, I can have them in the original file, that's not the problem. (And you are right of course, about the proper tracking of the previous value). I thought there must be an extractor pattern, but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: See how we unexpectedly don't have to cast after `case c: CCons[_]` when we select the head or the tail. Maybe the compiler considers `c` to be something like `CList[T] with CCons[_]`, which unambiguously resolves to `CCons[T]`?…